# How can I install "latest" via npm

Tags: npm, dependencies

When I use the following command (`foo` is example-only)

```bash
npm install foo@latest --save
```

and the latest version of `foo` is `16.3.1`, then the line that is added to `package.json` is

```json
"foo": "~16.3.1",
```

How can I make it actually add the string `"latest"`, like this

```json
"foo": "latest",
```

Note: Let’s avoid discussion about dependency management, just looking to see if this is technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

Defining "latest" always retrieves the latest available version from NPM. So at this time of writing the latest version is 16.3.1 but for example whenever the package gets updated at a later point to 16.3.2 the "latest" value will download 16.3.2 and so on.

If you always want the latest version at the time of "npm i" you should use the "latest" value, if you want a specific version (which I recommend since you can test the current available version but not the future available version) you should use a static version (e.g. 16.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set it to latest automatically, but you can set it to `"latest"` manually.
But setting it to "latest" would be considered bad practice. You usually dont change this stuff in the dependencies, because its done automatically.
So it's better to just keep it the way it is.